# VlFeat DEBUG macro

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, macros, vlfeat

I am using the VLFeat library (http://www.vlfeat.org/) in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

My problem is: Whenever I run the program, three Debug lines get printed to the console. I looked into the source code; it seems like these three lines only get printed if the macro DEBUG is defined.

Unfortunately, I can't find where the macro is defined; I didnt find it in the library's source and do not define it myself. I even tried to undefine it (#undef), which doesnt help.
Does anyone know if the macro is defined by the Visual cpp compiler and if yes, how to undefine it?

Comment: `DEBUG` is defined on the command line when invoking the compiler while building a debug/checked version of an object/executable.

Comment: Okay, so how to build a non-debug/checked version? Running or building in Release mode doesnt work

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was that the VLFeat version I used had been compiled in debug mode